# which is the effective way of having check whether it is Multiple If or having ArrayList check

Tags: if-statement

```
In my code I have to do the multiple if check ,
```

First method:
     boolean t1=true;
     boolean t2=true;
     boolean t3=false;
     boolean t4=true;
    ...t10=true;

```
if (t1 && t2 && t3 && t4 &&t5....&&t6)
{
..do s.omething...
}

or
```

Second Method:
 Having the check as like below code,

```
List<Boolean> list=new ArrayList<Boolean>
 Boolean t1=true;
 Boolean t2=true;
 Boolean t3=false;
 Boolean t4=true;
...t10=true;
list.add(t1);
list.add(t2);
.....
list.add(t10)

if(!list.contains(false))
{...
do something
}
```

which is most effective way of coding??

Comment: My guess, first one. Because it doesn't deal with class :D

Comment: @Nabin  class in the sense you are telling about generics???

Answer (score 0):

the first because it translates into a statically generated sequence of simple bit operations, without the need to iterate over complex list object.
but the second is more dynamic and thus its variations can be preferred in some cases, but not because of speed